# Unable to detect if the spritenode is moved to the left or right in spritekit (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Currently I'm making a game with swift spritekit and want the character look left when the finger moves the character to the left in touchesMoved. Since, I started development with swift and spritekit just a few days ago I find it hard to implement this action. How can I detect left or right in the code below ?

```
   override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            playerSprite.position.x = touch.locationInNode(self).x

        }
```

Comment: use a gesture recognizer that can detect left/right swipes. will be so much easier for you than using `touches:`

Comment: Does it mean that I should replace toucheMoved with a certain gesture recognizer ?

Comment: If you are using touchesMoved to drag a sprite around, then keep it, but to detect the left or right motion it will be easier to put in a gesture recognizer so that could change texture of sprite

Comment: Thanks!  I will try it !

Comment: good luck, I gave you a template below to start out with :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the current x-position of your touch is bigger or smaller than the position before.

To achieve that, you should create a variable to store the location of your last touch. For example:

```
var lastXTouch:CGFloat = -1
```

Then in the touchesMoved-method you check the location and check if the previous location was more on the left or more on the right side:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if lastXTouch > location.x{
            //Finger was moved to the left. Turn sprite to the left.
        }else{
            //Finger was moved to the right. Turn sprite to the right.
        }
        lastXTouch = location.x
        playerSprite.position.x = touch.locationInNode(self).x

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Christian! Your code works like a charm! Never thought it works this simple!

Comment: If you use the other answer(the one you've accepted) keep in mind that it does only work for swipes. It doesn't really react on the movement of your touches. A Swipe is something else than you really want(afaik).

Comment: @Christian If you drag your finger in any direction that's a swipe/pan .... So a gesture recognizer will work here. You do realize that a swipe or a pan IS by definition a movement of touches??

Comment: @MaxKargin yes I do. But the swiperecognizer isn't really suitable for his needs. Check the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/ the swipe has to be precise in one direction. Also the numberOfTouches has to be set etc.

Comment: @Christian Have you used swipes or pans before? the recognizer is doing what you have up here except it has built in error handling and its much safer. If you have a stray touch your method won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Put in a gesture recognizer when you want to be able to detect the swipe:

```
var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipe:"))
leftSwipe.direction = .Left

var rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipe:"))
rightSwipe.direction = .Right

self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
```

Then, you need to implement the handler method that is called - `handleSwipe:`

```
func handleSwipe(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
   if (sender.direction == .Left){
       //swiped left
       //change your texture here on the sprite node to make it look left
   }
   if (sender.direction == .Right){
       //swipe right
       //change texture here on sprite to make it look right
   }
}
```